# How do i get the file path document that is being open by my wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf, file-format

so i have a c# application that can save and open files. Windows explorer is registered to open that file format with my application. But how do i get the file path of the file that i double clicked in windows explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you get it via commandline - on how to read those arguments see for example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970914.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I must have overlooked this when I was searching for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your App.xaml.cs file should have an AppStartingUp method.  The event args contain the command line arguments of the program.  The first should be the file name:

```
public partial class app : Application
{
    void AppStartingUp(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        string file_name = e.Args[0];

        ...
    }

}
```